# How to use MFA with SQL Server Datasource embedded in MS Excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, azure, datasource

I have an excel file that retrieves data from Azure SQL Database. I want to force MFA on the connection. I have gone through MS documentation and set up connection string as recommended in the documentation.

```
server=server;database=database;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;
```

When I use this in SSMS, it works like a charm. I get text message with authentication code. But when I use the same connection string inside excel file, it simply prompts with a login dialog box and asking to end credentials.

Is there a way to enable MFA for SQL Server connection when it is embedded in Excel file?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. If you have any other concerns, please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Hello @ByteBlocks, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is no document talk about how to configure MFA as the default authentication when connect to Azure SQL database from Excel.

But we can use MFA to connect to SQL database by some other ways. You could follow my steps:

I'm using Excel 2016.

**1. Data-->From Other Sources-->From Data Connection Wizard:**

[image]

**2. Select: Other/Advanced**

[image]

**3. Choose Microsoft OLEDB Driver for Sql Server, Next:**

[image]

**4. We can using the MAF authentication to connect to the Azure SQL:**

[image]

**5. Choose the table:**

[image]

Comment: This does not really solve my problem. But it is good piece of information.